# merging two dataframes with same rows and indexes in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I'm trying to merge two pandas dataframes that have common row indexes and common columns 0,1,2 but different column 3, so the resulting dataframe has columns from both:

First dataframe:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 817 entries, 0 to 816
Data columns (total 3 columns):
0    817 non-null int64
1    817 non-null int64
2    817 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(1), int64(2)
memory usage: 19.2 KB


0   1       2
0   1950    1   -0.060310
1   1950    2   0.626810
2   1950    3   -0.008128
3   1950    4   0.555100
4   1950    5   0.071577
```

Second dataframe:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 817 entries, 0 to 816
Data columns (total 3 columns):
0    817 non-null int64
1    817 non-null int64
2    817 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(1), int64(2)
memory usage: 19.2 KB

0   1       2
0   1950    1   0.92
1   1950    2   0.40
2   1950    3   -0.36
3   1950    4   0.73
4   1950    5   -0.59
```

So far I tried with merge:

```
pd.merge(df, df2, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='outer')
```

But results are not what I expect:

```
    0_x     1_x     2_x     0_y     1_y     2_y
0   1950    1   -0.060310   1950    1   0.92
1   1950    2   0.626810    1950    2   0.40
2   1950    3   -0.008128   1950    3   -0.36
3   1950    4   0.555100    1950    4   0.73
4   1950    5   0.071577    1950    5   -0.59
```

And with concat:

```
pd.concat([df, df2], axis=1, ignore_index=True).head()


0   1       2       3       4       5
0   1950    1   -0.060310   1950    1   0.92
1   1950    2   0.626810    1950    2   0.40
2   1950    3   -0.008128   1950    3   -0.36
3   1950    4   0.555100    1950    4   0.73
4   1950    5   0.071577    1950    5   -0.59
```

I'm expecting something like

```
0   1       2       3     
0   1950    1   -0.060310    0.92
1   1950    2   0.626810     0.40
2   1950    3   -0.008128    -0.36
3   1950    4   0.555100     0.73
4   1950    5   0.071577     -0.59
```

**EDIT**: Maybe I was unclear and I apologize if so, I'm trying to add the  last column from the second dataset in the resulting one, so I have the same year, month, value1 and then value2 columns

Comment: `df.merge(df2, on=[0, 1])`?

Comment: First, there doesn't seem to be a column named 3 anywhere in your example.  I'm assuming you are trying to join on the index and on columns 1 and 2.  Have you tried `pd.merge(df,df2, on = [1,2])`?  Could you be more explicit on what are columns and what are indexes?

Comment: What is stopping you from dropping columns 4 and 5 after the concat command? Is it not going to be even easier to use df1['new'] = df2.iloc[:, 2] instead?

Comment: Your question statement is misleading: cols 0,1,2 are the same, only your unnamed column 3 differs in each.

Comment: Ok, so what I'm trying to do is add column 3 in second dataset as column 4 in the merged dataset

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would try:

```
pd.merge(df, df2, on=['0', '1'])
```

maybe

```
pd.merge(df, df2, on=[0,1]
```

Comment: this worked pd.merge(df, df2, on=[0, 1]), just need to renames columns, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

```
df.merge(df2, on=1)
```

you don't need to add index column, once they have same index. And it can be a inner join by default.

Your error was made the merge just by index, the merge function doesn't know that the column 1 is equal in both data.